# How to ignore specified word in text?

Tags: google-translate

I'm using java version of translate API in app engine. 
Is there a way to ignore specific word in translation eg:
"Translate IGNORED_TEXT this", for some languages IGNORED_TEXT is malformed and it's not guaranteed that Translate API will not change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempts I've ended up with a kind of retrier, which was using special character for the text I wanted to ignore. In My case they were string parameters(%d, %s etc.). Maybe it will be a help for someone:

```
public class Parser {

public static final String[] MAGIC_PARAMETER_STRING = {"975313579", "*****", "˨", "இ", "⏲"};
public static final String[] MAGIC_PARAMETER_NUMBER = {"975323579", "*******", "Ω", "˧", "\u23FA"};
private static final String formatSpecifier
        = "%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])";
private static final Pattern formatToken = Pattern.compile(formatSpecifier);
private final int maxStringParameterCount = Parser.MAGIC_PARAMETER_STRING.length;
private final int maxNumberParameterCount = Parser.MAGIC_PARAMETER_NUMBER.length;
private int stringPos = 0;
private int numberPos = 0;

private String convertToken(ConvertedString result, String index, String flags, String width, String precision, String temporal, String conversion, String numberReplacement, String stringReplacement) {
    if (conversion.equals("s")) {
        result.stringArgCount++;
        return stringReplacement;
    } else if (conversion.equals("d")) {
        result.numberArgCount++;
        return numberReplacement;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("%" + index + flags + width + precision + temporal + conversion);
}

private String getReplacementNumber(boolean bumpUp) throws RetryExceededException {
    if (bumpUp) {
        ++numberPos;
    }
    if (numberPos >= maxNumberParameterCount) {
        throw new RetryExceededException();
    }
    return MAGIC_PARAMETER_NUMBER[numberPos];
}

private String getReplacementString(boolean bumpUp) throws RetryExceededException {
    if (bumpUp) {
        ++stringPos;
    }
    if (stringPos >= maxStringParameterCount) {
        throw new RetryExceededException();
    }
    return MAGIC_PARAMETER_STRING[stringPos];
}

public ConvertedString revert(String text) throws RetryExceededException {
    ConvertedString convertedString = new ConvertedString();
    String replacementString = getReplacementString(false);
    String replacementNumber = getReplacementNumber(false);
    convertedString.stringArgCount = StringUtils.countMatches(text, replacementString);
    convertedString.numberArgCount = StringUtils.countMatches(text, replacementNumber);
    String result = text.replace(replacementString, "%s");
    result = result.replace(replacementNumber, "%d");
    convertedString.result = result;
    return convertedString;
}

public ConvertedString convert(final String format) {
    return convert(format, MAGIC_PARAMETER_NUMBER[0], MAGIC_PARAMETER_STRING[0]);
}

public ConvertedString convert(final String format, String numberReplacement, String stringReplacement) {
    ConvertedString result = new ConvertedString();
    final StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    final Matcher matcher = formatToken.matcher(format);
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        regex.append(format.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start()));
        regex.append(convertToken(result, matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3),
                matcher.group(4), matcher.group(5), matcher.group(6), numberReplacement, stringReplacement));
        lastIndex = matcher.end();
    }
    regex.append(format.substring(lastIndex, format.length()));
    result.result = regex.toString();
    return result;
}

public ConvertedString retryConvert(String originalText, boolean bumpUpString, boolean bumpUpNumber) throws RetryExceededException {
    String replacementNumber = getReplacementNumber(bumpUpNumber);
    String replacementString = getReplacementString(bumpUpString);
    return convert(originalText, replacementNumber, replacementString);
}

public static class ConvertedString {
    public int stringArgCount;
    public int numberArgCount;
    public String result;

}

public static class RetryExceededException extends Exception {

}
}
```

Comment: Clear description how you do it would be much better than wall of code, which is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

replace `IGNORED_TEXT` to `<span class="notranslate">IGNORED_TEXT</span>`.

Edit: It will not work using GUI on https://translate.google.com/, but it will work using API on https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2.

<s>**Solution #2**:</s>

replace `IGNORED_TEXT` to its md5, translate everything, then replace it back. (works with %s, %1$s, abc) - Edit: does not work with some language like Serbian.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=pl&text=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22notranslate%22%3Esomething%3C%2Fspan%3E&op=translate
first solution does not work, is deprecated?

Comment: @IHaveHandedInMyResignation You are right and wrong. It works, but only using API. But i updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@ViliusL**, your answer led me to the solution to my issue. I was strugling with excluding part of text from translating. Currently I have not found any hints(stackoverflow, google) so I leave answer in this topic.

In my case problem was in wrong mime type. If you use google cloud translate api (version 2 or 3 - it does not matter which), you have to set mime type "**text/html**" instead of "text/plain". If you have text/plain mime type google will ignore part of html tags and class="notranslate". Example is below:

```
   TranslateTextResponse requestForTranslation() {
      try (TranslationServiceClient client = googleTranslationServiceProvider.getClient()) {
         return client.translateText(buildRequest());
      }
   }


    TranslateTextRequest buildRequest() {
        return TranslateTextRequest.newBuilder()
                .setParent("YOUR_PARENT")
                .setMimeType("text/html") // HERE should be text/html
                .setSourceLanguageCode("DE")
                .setTargetLanguageCode("EN")
                .addContents("<span class=\"notranslate\">etwas auf deutsch</span>")
                .build();
    }
```

reference: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats

PS.
I've noticed that you can use tags "<>" to exclude translation, like below:

```
 .addContents("<etwas auf deutsch>")
```